# Django Model Entries Not Available to Other Developers

Tags: python, django, migration

I have manually added entries (rows) to the models in my Django project through the admin interface.

I have also ran the following commands 
`python3 manage.py makemigrations` & 
`python3 manage.py migrate`

The issue is I am the only one that can see the data in the database, and other developers cannot see them.

They are all using the same project files as present on my computer.

Comment: Why should other developers be able to see updates in your local dev database?

Comment: You're right. I used `mysql -u username -p database_name > filename.sql` to dump data and reloaded it on the other computer using `mysql -u username -p database_name < filename.sql`

Comment: edit: `mysqldump -u username -p database_name > filename.sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your database file also included with "project files". If you use the local `sqlite3` file generated by Django or really any other local database file that isn't in production and the other developers don't have this why would they see your updates to the DB?

Comment: I am so silly! I thought the project would contain the database files. I had to dump and load the data from mysql on the other computer.